# DNS lookup in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to do a simple lookup, for example convert "perdu.com" in "208.97.177.124". I tried using Network.DNS.Lookup since that's the first result on google, and it works fine :

```
rs <- makeResolvSeed defaultResolvConf
eIp <- withResolver rs $ \resolver -> lookupA resolver $ BS.pack "perdu.com"
```

The problem is that seems to be ignoring the /etc/hosts file. What is the correct way in Haskell to resolve a domain "normally", like other software like ping or any browser would do it ? I'm assuming Network.DNS.Lookup implements a full recursive resolver instead of just using the C functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import Network.BSD (getHostByName, hostAddress)
import Network.Socket (inet_ntoa)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

resolve address = do
  ent <- getHostByName address
  inet_ntoa (hostAddress ent)

main = resolve "perdu.com" >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: No need to do `name <- x ; return name`, we can simply use `x`.